# issue while deploying applicationset using list generator in argocd

Tags: kubernetes, devops, amazon-eks, argocd, gitops

I am deploying application set using list generator in argocd. My yaml is as below,

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  name: guestbook
  namespace: default
spec:
  generators:
  - list:
      elements:
      - cluster: local-cluster
        url: https://kubernetes.default.svc
      - cluster: test-eks-remote
        url: https://xxxx.xx.ap-south-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  template:
    metadata:
      name: '{{cluster}}-guestbook'
      namespace: default
    spec:
      project: default
      source:
        repoURL: https://github.com/hardikpatel29/argocd-examples.git
        targetRevision: master
        path: guestbook
      destination:
        server: '{{url}}'
        namespace: guestbook
      syncPolicy:
         syncOptions:
          - CreateNamespace=true
```

when I am hitting

```
kubectl apply -f applicationset-list-generator.yaml
```

getting error

> resource mapping not found for name: "guestbook" namespace:
> "default" from "applicationset-list-generator.yaml": no matches for
> kind "ApplicationSet" in version "argoproj.io/v1alpha1" ensure CRDs
> are installed first

what have i missed?

Comment: What is the output of `kubectl api-resources | grep ApplicationSet`?

Comment: @larsks nothing.

Comment: It sounds like your installation doesn't have support for ApplicationSets. According to [these docs](https://argocd-applicationset.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Getting-Started/), if you're running argocd earlier than 2.3 you need to install the applicationset controller separately.

Comment: @larsks I have installed separately. Its working. I am able to deploy applicationset.

Comment: does it work if you create the appSet in the argocd namespace ?